# Insert data in two separate tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am fiddling with some code to pass time, and I am unsure if I'm doing this the right way. I would really appreciate suggestions if possible of better ways of doing this.

I took a query and added a union to make essentially the same query but with a variable that has text attached to it such as 'IN'.

below you will see what i have tried, I did various things but i fear I'm wasting my time since surely there are a better way of making this work.

```php
<?php 
require_once("connection/link.php");
 if(
     (isset($_POST['id'])&& $_POST['id'] !='') && 
 (isset($_POST['upc'])&& $_POST['upc'] !='') && 
 (isset($_POST['category'])&& $_POST['category'] !='') &&
 (isset($_POST['state'])&& $_POST['state'] !='') &&
 (isset($_POST['quantity'])&& $_POST['quantity'] !='')
    )
    { 
$id = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$upc = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['upc']);
$category = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
$quantity = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);
$state = "IN";
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='".$id."'");

    if (!$query)
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

    echo "Product code already exists";
    } else
    {
$sql="INSERT INTO products (id, upc, category, quantity) 
        VALUES ('".$id."', '".$upc."', '".$category."', '".$quantity."')
            UNION
        INSERT INTO transactions (id, upc, category, quantity, state) 
        VALUES ('".$id."', '".$upc."', '".$category."', '".$quantity."', '".$state."')";
if(!$result = $link->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');
    }   
else
    {
echo "Product was added successfully!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This would create a historic log of all products added and whether they are IN or OUT. Mind you this is just the IN part of this whole ordeal.

Comment: You have to do two separate queries. You can only use `UNION` to combine `SELECT` queries, not anything else.

Comment: You should also learn to use prepared statements and parameters rather than concatenating variables into SQL.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: You should create two separate prepared statements and execute them one after the other.

Comment: So this is what i am doing now except im not doing prepared statements as i dont know how yet. 

If i have two queries can't i just run them both like this ?
```if(!$result = $link->query($sql, $sql1)){

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do two separate queries. Put them into a transaction to ensure that they're done atomically.

You should also use prepared statements to prevent SQL-injection.

You don't need a variable for `IN`, you can just hard-code it into the SQL.

```
if(!empty($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['upc']) && !empty($_POST['category']) && !empty($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['quantity'])) {
    $prod_stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO products (id, upc, category, quantity, state) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $prod_stmt->bind_param("issi", $_POST['id'], $_POST['upc'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['quantity']);
    $trans_stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO transactions (id, upc, category, quantity, state) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 'IN')");
    $trans_stmt->bind_param("issi", $_POST['id'], $_POST['upc'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['quantity']);
    $link->begin_transaction();
    $prod_stmt->execute();
    $trans_stmt->execute();
    $link->commit();
}
```

You can also use `!empty(variable)` instead of checking both `isset(variable)` and `variable != ''` (note that this simplification isn't appropriate for variables where `0` or `null` are valid values, since that's considered empty).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that @Barmar, I tried it but, it has not worked although it gave no errors. I added values such as
```VALUES ('".$id."', '".$upc."', '".$category."', '".$quantity."')");```

&
```VALUES ('".$id."', '".$upc."', '".$category."', '".$quantity."', 'IN')");```

The code is intact other than that. Any idea why ?

heres a screenshot of my file. [link](https://i.gyazo.com/9650c7904248a958edb43425f07fbbd0.png)

Comment: Add error checking to the code, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments

Comment: So i Added ```mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);``` before my mysqli connection but still i dont get any errors.